# How to set nodes in a treeview to start off checked if a checkbox on a previous window is selected

Tags: winforms, powershell

First time Posting on this site. I hope I have the information formatted correctly.

I am designing a simple windows form to help create change control forms to track employee access. It is a 2 part form. The main form asks for some user input and there is a checkbox at the bottom that they can select if they are requesting a standard user setup. When they click next in the main form a child form window pops up that contains a treeview and a comments section for any special notes. What I am trying to do is have some nodes automatically checked if the 'Standard Setup' box is checked in the main form.

> When I run the code I get a error stating "Method invocation failed because First[System.Windows.Forms.TreeView] does not contain a method named 'checknode'."

My standard setup box is $checkboxStandardSetup and if it has been checked then I want to have it place a checkbox next to these nodes in the treeview. If it isn't checked no other modification need to be made in the treeview. Here is a snippet of what I have.

```
if ($checkboxStandardSetup.Checked)
    {
        $treeview1.checknode("7")
        $treeview1.checknode("8")
        $treeview1.checknode("9")
        $treeview1.checknode("10")
        $treeview1.checknode("11")
        $treeview1.checknode("12")
        $treeview1.checknode("14")
        $treeview1.checknode("20")
    }
```

I have also tried to use

```
if ($checkboxStandardSetup.Checked)
    {
        $treeview1.node7.checked
        $treeview1.node8.checked
        $treeview1.node9.checked
        $treeview1.node10.checked
        $treeview1.node11.checked
        $treeview1.node12.checked
        $treeview1.node14.checked
        $treeview1.node20.checked
    }
```

But to no avail. The function below works to parse through and then output a list of the checked nodes but I can't get the standard setup box to apply those checks.

```
Function Get-CheckedNodes
    {
        param ( 
            [ValidateNotNull()]     
            [System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection]$NodeCollection,       
            [ValidateNotNull()]     
            [System.Collections.ArrayList]$CheckedNodes)
        foreach ($Node in $NodeCollection)
        {
            if ($Node.Checked)
            {
                [void]$CheckedNodes.Add($Node)
            }
            Get-CheckedNodes $Node.Nodes $CheckedNodes
        }
    }
```

To call the function I use

```
$checkedNodes = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Get-CheckedNodes $treeview1.Nodes $CheckedNodes
    foreach ($node in $CheckedNodes)
    {
        Write-Output $node.text | Out-File -append C:\Change\UserForm$(Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yy').csv
    }
```

I expected the treeview list to have a checkbox next to the nodes that I coded but instead I get the above error. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: This is a WinForm or WPF MDI GUI question not really a PowerShell code issue one. So, off topic for this Q&A. I suggest you move this to the CodeReview Q&A https://codereview.stackexchange.com and post your complete code for feedback. Yet, since you are here, you would need to do this as an MDI child Parent model, and fire of code using the onload event of the child to set initial option of the child. Lastly, WinFomrs is not getting any real attention (maintenance only), so, it's time to move to WPF for current / future GUI stuff.

Comment: Thank you for looking! I will look into WPF and try to get things moved over to that. I'm new to developing things so it would probably be best to start with something that is going to be around for a while.

Comment: Now worries. Yep, WPF, is the thing, and PowerShell is a gateway drug to C#, so, may as well get over there. Also as you look at your treeview checkbox thing, there are a few discussions on it here of course, with issues encountered and here is a sample project you may want to look over... https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView